# Conditional/limited access in a controller/view? (MVC2)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I have two roles being used on my site currently, author & admin. Authors cannot access user administration functions. However, they should be able to edit certain parts of their profile. An admin is currently able to edit all parts of a user's profile. For example:

```
employee ID   [admin]
display name  [author,admin]
roles         [admin]
```

I would like to re-use code where possible. I'm not sure what the best solution would be here. There are 2 things to deal with

1. Only allowing a user to edit their own profile and not others
2. Restricting which fields that user can edit vs which fields an admin can edit

I think #1 is best achieved by a custom Authorize attribute (I already have one I can extend further). If you have a better approach please share. And #2 I am unsure, view model? I have my allowed fields bound for a user using a partial class which would be different for each role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution for #1 is spot on, you need to use the `AuthorizeAttribute`.

For #2 you can just do security trimming where you only *render* for the particular user.

Some pseudo code in your view (or move it to a partial view):

```
if administrator
    render employee ID text box
if administrator || author
    render display name text box
if administrator
    render roles check list
```

So you're going to need to control how to determine if the user is in a "role". You can use [ASP.NET's Membership Provider](http://dotnetaddict.dotnetdevelopersjournal.com/aspnet35_membership.htm) or roll something of your own.

Comment: True. And it looks like UpdateModel() has third/fourth parameters so I can explicitly include/exclude properties that the user should/shouldn't be able to update. Thanks